# Size of WebDataset in Pytorch

Tags: pytorch

When it comes to the Pytorch Dataloader which takes a default dataset (e.g. datasets.ImageFolder), we can find the size of a dataset that is used by the dataloader with `len(dataloader)`. However, what about WebDataset?
As WebDataset is a PyTorch Dataset, is it possible to get the size of a loader which takes a WebDataset?

https://webdataset.github.io/webdataset/

Answer (score 1):

WebDataset doesn't provide a `__len__` method, as it conforms to the PyTorch `IterableDataset` interface. `IterableDataset` is designed for stream-like data, and considers it wrong to have a `len()`.

If you have code that depends on `len()` to be available, you can set the length to some value using `with_length()`:

```
>>> dataset = wds.WebDataset(url)
>>> len(dataset)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: object of type 'WebDataset' has no len()
>>> dataset = dataset.with_length(10)
>>> len(dataset)
10
```